# node.js dns library does not like our RDS hostname

Tags: node.js, http, dns

I am getting this error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value
>   "blue-test.cl3fvy5cqe1x.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" is invalid for
>   option "hostname"

this is what generates the error:

```
const dns = require('dns');

const getDNSInfo = (host, port) => new Promise(resolve => {
  dns.lookupService(host, port, (err, hostname, service) => {
    console.log('dns resolved:', {hostname, service, err});
    resolve({err, hostname, service});
  });
});
```

anyone know why it wouldn't like that argument? seems weird

Comment: It works fine when you put "normal" name, like www.google.com?

Comment: it doesn't, I get: `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "google.com" is invalid for option "hostname"`

Answer (score 0):

the correct call to use for dns names is `dns.lookup` not `dns.lookupService`:

```
const dns = require('dns');

const getDNSInfo = (host) => new Promise(resolve => {
  dns.lookup(host, (err, address, service) => {
    console.log('dns resolved:', {address, service, err});
    resolve({err, address, service});
  });
});
```